# How to import a Amplitude js in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just got into web developing and have this 'basic' question.. I have built this website for my brother who is an artist and I am trynna import 'Amplitude js' into the html so I can use that audio player to play his musics. I just want the player to be in the center of the page, not the whole page.

The source files are on https://github.com/521dimensions/amplitudejs

I have tried using the 3rd method explained, and included

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/amplitudejs@{{3.2.1}}/dist/amplitude.js"></script>
```

in my html head section. Nothing is happening.

I just don't understand how to implement it into my html so it shows up in the page.

Any idea on something I might be missing out ?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have used   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/amplitudejs@{{3.2.1}}/dist/amplitude.js"></script>
in the head section of my html but nothing is changing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read the following about what needs to be included in a good question, then use the edit link under the question to update it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

First, you must include resource javascript, like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/amplitudejs@{{version-number}}/dist/amplitude.js"></script>
```

Second, call Amplitude.init({options}), like this :

```
Amplitude.init({
    "songs": [
        {
            "name": "Song Name 1",
            "artist": "Artist Name",
            "album": "Album Name",
            "url": "/song/url.mp3",
            "cover_art_url": "/cover/art/url.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Song Name 2",
            "artist": "Artist Name",
            "album": "Album Name",
            "url": "/song/url.mp3",
            "cover_art_url": "/cover/art/url.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Song Name 3",
            "artist": "Artist Name",
            "album": "Album Name",
            "url": "/song/url.mp3",
            "cover_art_url": "/cover/art/url.jpg"
        }
    ]
});
```

Last, declare amplitude html, like this :

```
<span class="button amplitude-play-pause amplitude-paused" amplitude-playlist-main-play-pause="true" amplitude-playlist="{index}"></span> //Play pause button
```

And this is basic example from amplitude js:

https://github.com/521dimensions/amplitudejs/blob/dev/examples/blue-playlist/index.html

Comment: Thank for replying!
This is still a bit confusing for me.. I know that the first script should go into the main section, where should I paste this Amplitude.init ? in the css or the html ?

Comment: inside script tag , you can try that example first then create your own app

Answer (score 2):

This is because Your head section of HTML is not fetching javascript from the CDN.

As per documentation, You will need to put version number.

Here is right example:

For Latest version do not use any number.

ex:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/amplitudejs/dist/amplitude.js"></script>`

and For any version, just put your number after @

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/amplitudejs@4.1.0/dist/amplitude.js"></script>`

Now you can use your script to call js function anywhere under the html section, best to call your script before ending body section.